# Url Rewriting Error show this error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I upload .htaccess file and show this error 404.. Please tell me how can I solve.

My .htaccess code is here :

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php    
RewriteRule ^news$ news.php
```

Comment: On which URL's do you get a 404 error?

Comment: www.test.com/news e.g @Marc

Comment: @Marc can you tell me before uploading.htaccess file we need to setting iis ??

Comment: As long as the files (`news.php` and `index.php`) exist, the .htaccess should be fine.

Comment: How it's related to MySqli?

Comment: htaccess seems ok ..

Comment: @zeshan Do you still need an answer for his?

Comment: @5ervant if you give me correctly guide ..

Comment: @zeshan What do you want to do? Do you want to redirect *"/index"* to *"/index.php"* and *"/news"* to *"/news.php"* ?

Comment: yes. because when i upload in server this code is not working and show error 404.@5ervant

Answer (score 0):

The `404` error message is telling that the requested page is **Not Found**.

To redirect *"/index"* to *"/index.php"* and *"/news"* to *"/news.php"*, you can use these directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(index/?|news/?)+$ $1.php [R=302,NC]
```

When that code succeed then replace the instance of `R=302` with `R=301` like `[R=301,NC]` and save it again. When you messed with `R=301` *"Permanently Redirected"* flag then you need to clear you browser cache before checking.